# Custom fields: In what order are they saved into the DB?

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

If I insert multiple custom fields to my article, they get sorted in *"I don't know what"* way. So when I insert some multiple fields in an article and call those via

```
$cf = get_post_custom();
foreach ($cf['ISSUU-configID'] as $key => $value) {
  echo "<h4>" . $cf['ISSUU-configID'][$key] . "</h4>\n";
}
```

their order is mixed up and neither logically ordered nor in the way I inserted them. Seems weird to me.

To make it a little clearer:
I insert these numbers, each one in an own custom field (in specifically that order):
12345, 23456, 34567, 45678

And the output will be something like (in fact this is always different):
45678, 23456, 12345, 34567

Answer (score 2):

The SQL query triggered by `get_post_custom()` is in `update_meta_cache()` and it looks like this:

```
$wpdb->get_results( 
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT $column, meta_key, meta_value FROM $table WHERE $column IN ($id_list)",
        $meta_type
    ), 
    ARRAY_A 
);
```

So there is no `ORDER BY` given.

Without `ORDER BY` the resulting order is almost unpredictable: it depends on the optimizer, used indexes and *their* order.

The order the fields are *saved* doesn’t matter here.

You can filter `'query'` and add an `ORDER BY` clause to the query. See `wp-includes/wp-db.php` – `wpdb::query()` for details.

Comment: so there is no way to order those, am i right? would be neat, if they would be saved, the way i enter them..

Comment: @honk31 See my update for a way to get a specific order.

Comment: @honk31 Have you considered saving all numbers as an array and as one single metavalue? You would not have to worry about (de-)serialization, `get_post_meta` and `update_post_meta` would handle that for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can call custom fields individually via the `get_post_meta` function:

```
$meta = get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single ) //last argument is Boolean to return a single object or an array
```

More info about it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).  This way you can call your custom fields how ever you want.

Comment: that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to mr. pille for the push in the right direction. i created a new custom field with multiple values devided by "|" and use php explode to get my values:

```
$cf = get_post_custom();
if ($cf['ISSUU-multiID'][0]) {
  $ids = explode("|", $cf['ISSUU-multiID'][0]);
  foreach ($ids as $key => $id) {
    echo "<h4>" . $id . "</h4>\n";
  }
}
```

...since i shall not edit any wp core files... thanks for the help...

Comment: While you're obviously in the clear if you have found a solution that works and satisfies you, a manual explode of a concatenated string was not exactly what I meant - `update_post_meta` will simply accept a regular array as the `value` argument. Also I don't think you quite grasped what toscho was suggesting - he *wasn't* proposing editing the core.

Comment: nope. not core, you are right. but im far from being a php coder, and i once tried to get my head around php :: stuff (i guess its called classes) and i totally failed. but could you explain to me, how a value of your solution would look like? examples make the world so much easier..